# What is appropriate UML class relationship?

Tags: uml

In my case, what is appropriate relationship between CarBuilder and SuperCar (SportCar as well)?

Explanation: CarBuilder holds an array of Car class's instance but it doesn't construct any instance of Car class. Instead, it constructs SportCar, and SuperCar classes' instances by directly call CreateInstance() method of these two classes.

Class Diagram:[CarBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNbjB.png)

Comment: Why the C+ tag?

Comment: post the code so the class relation will become clear

Comment: CarBuilder is an aggregation of Car. SportCar and SuperCar both extends Car.

Comment: You already have a relation defined. So what is the question?

Comment: @RichardCritten I removed  the incorrected tag.

Comment: @GweltazNiquel, But CarBuilder doesn't hold any instance of SportCar and SuperCar classes.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, My question is "In my case, what is appropriate relationship between CarBuilder and SuperCar (SportCar as well)?"

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are describing three different relationships -- a compositional one (that you already have), and then two others to the constructors of SuperCar and SportCar. So I'd just add an association to SuperCar and SportCar from CarBuilder.

Incidentally, it seems unlikely that you'd only ever have a car composed within CarBuilder -- maybe you mean a (weak) aggregate rather than a composition? Surely a car can exist outside CarBuilder? Also, this looks like a partial implementation of the strategy pattern, might be worth looking whether that's relevant.